# Soundcloud API: how to play only a part of a track?

Tags: soundcloud

For an upcoming project I am investigating the possibility to play only a certain length (for example 20s) of a track, using the Soundcloud API.

Could anybody indicate me if that is possible, or should a different track with that limited length be created separately?

Many thanks !
Maarten (WebForDreams)

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways you can do this. Are you going to be using the JavaScript SDK or the player widget? For the player widget, you can just use [seekTo()](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/widget#methods).

If you're using the JavaScript SDK you can use the [setPosition()](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/#soundmanager-setposition) method:

```
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'foo'
});
SC.whenStreamingReady(function() {
  var sound = SC.stream(52933447);
  sound.setPosition(2000); // position, measured in milliseconds
  sound.play();
});
```

If you want to stop at a particular point, you could use [onPosition()](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/#smsound-onposition).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Paul, better late than never, thank you very much for your answer. The project has just been kicked off, so will probably need a solution like the one you proposed. All the best and thanks again!