# Soundcloud API: Fetch parts of multiple tracks to save them as merged HTML5 audio without loading whole lengths

Tags: javascript, html, api, audio, soundcloud

I am very new to Soundcloud API and have problems getting started. So please help me to get this right. I am going to use the Javascript SDK with the aim of fetching parts of several tracks to put them together into one HTML5 audio object. For several reasons I do not want to load the whole length of the tracks.

My question can be divided into two sub-questions:

1. Is it possible to get only a part of a track from Soundcloud without
   fetching the whole song?
2. How can a fetched (part of a) track be saved as (or transformed into a) HTML5 audio element?

As I have understood, in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820504/soundcloud-api-how-to-play-only-a-part-of-a-track) the whole track will be loaded while *setPosition()* and *onPosition()* are used to define the relevant part to be played.

I am looking for something like this:

```
//pseudo-code
var tracks_array = [{track-id, start_pos, end_pos}, ... , n];

get_tracks (tracks_array) 
{
  var audio = document.createElement("AUDIO");

  audio = awesome_function(tracks_array[]); // for all n

}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: is it possible to merge audio files? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305530/combining-audio-files-in-html

Comment: @Sabarish I am not sure, but I thought it would be possible "by adding their channel data" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709391/merge-multiple-audio-buffer-sources
OR using this kind of workaround https://codewala.net/2013/02/24/html5-set-multiple-audiovideo-files-dynamically-and-run-one-by-one/

Comment: if, i understood correctly, its not merging the stream, but plays one after another like "auto play" in the play list.